# Xamarin.iOS Trailing Space constraints do not set

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, constraints

I'm trying to add constraints to my View Controller.

I can set constraints for Top/Bottom space without issue, but setting Trailing Space (left and right sides) of the View doesn't do anything anymore. I can drag the pin but it won't "attach" to anything.

This isn't just happening on new Views; all of the previously existing Views I've made also can no longer have constraints set.

I've tried rebuilding my solution, making an entirely new storyboard, updating Visual Studio and Xamarin on both  my Mac and Windows machine. Nothing seems to be working.

Using Xamarin.iOS SDK version 11.2.0.8 on both my Windows machine and Mac.
Visual Studio 2017 v. 15.4.0, Windows 10

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code?

Comment: Constraints on `storyboard` is different from `Xib`. Top constraint is related to Top Layout Guide .bottom is related to Bottom Layout Guide , and when we set Leading and Trailing constraint , there are a little space ,we can not drag the pin to the left or right edge.

Comment: @JeroenHeier There is no code, the Xamarin storyboard designer is graphical only; an aspect that makes it really frustrating.